# Oracle SQL - Retrieve select and new column with the sum of an existing column

Tags: sql, oracle

So, I am running a large query that returns n columns, but additionally, i would like to retrieve another column as the sum of an existing column.

I know that this works:

```
select A.*, (select sum(column_n) from my_query) from my_query A
```

The problem is my_query is quite large and I don't want to repeat it twice.

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select q.*, sum(column_n) over ()
from my_query q;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!